# Questions about passive voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

They had made a good use of the house.

-> (a) A good use had been made of the house.

-> (a)' The house had been made a good use of.

The original sentence is understandable(also in Korean too), but Passive sentence (a), (a)' is not directly translatable to Korean.(I'm a Korean)

I wonder if (a), (a)' would make sense to a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A good use had been made of the house.` makes perfect sense, but without the initial "A" would be more normal.

`The house had been made a good use of.` doesn't sound right. Slightly better as `The house had been made good use of.` but still clumsy, and unnatural sounding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your answer is very helpful !!!

Comment: For that matter, the original sentence doesn't need the article either. "They made good use of the house" is also more idiomatic

Comment: Thank you for your reply.